# Incorrect personal pronoun case in "I Wonder as I Wander"

Tags: grammatical-case, christmas

In the Christmas song "I Wonder as I Wander", the lyrics say:

> I wonder as I wander out under the sky,
>   How Jesus the Savior did come for to die.
>   For poor on'ry people like you and like I

It seems to me, though, that "like" here is a preposition--so shouldn't that mean that it should say "like me", not "like I"?

Am I missing a rule of English here, or is it just a breaking-the-rules-for-poetry thing?

Comment: Now I'm curious as to what *on'ry* means...

Comment: @JAM - Probably "ordinary". However, that dialect has the wonderful world [ornery](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ornery), which means "stubborn" (affectionately). According to wicktionary, the latter Appalachian word traces its etymology back to the former. Given this song's odd history (see my answer below), it is tough to tell exactly which was intended (and by whom). Perhaps even a combination of both.

Comment: @Jam: See earlier question - [Meaning of a contraction, “on'ry,” in I wonder as I wander"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139874/)

Comment: Er, "under sky" and "like I". I don't think "like me" would work here. Though, usage *"like you and I"* (like *"between you and I"*) would be grammatical standard English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Interesting coincidence that it is so recent. I've made my point about the word there now.

Comment: @F.E., I would hesitate quite a long time (and ultimately decide not to) before labelling _between/like you and I_ as “grammatical standard English”. Fairly common, yes; but not common or—more importantly—commonly _accepted_ enough that it’s grammatical. Not in Standard English, at least.

Comment: @F.E.: "between you and I" is as correct as "between we" is correct. If you say "between us", then "between you and me" is (by parallel construction) correct.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet and KeithB: Well, I tossed out some chum, er, bait, and got some bites. If one of you open a question on this topic (e.g. "between you and I"), then I'll probably come by and show you some vetted sources that consider that type of expression to be grammatical (in Standard English).

Comment: @F.E., I'm sure you can find vetted sources to claim that. You can also find vetted sources to claim that English does not have tenses and that ‘me’ is grammatical as the (sole) subject of a finite verb in Standard English. The fact that something can be logically argued from a linguistic viewpoint doesn't mean it's either true or should be adhered to. I would not call something that a large percentage of speakers find to be impossible constructions grammatical in its commonest sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Well, what about the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), would that satisfy you?

Comment: @F.E., it's not about satisfying _me_. _I_ still wouldn't call it grammatical, but I realise others do. I do hope they mention the caveat that it is not unobjectionably grammatical, at least.

Comment: @F.E.: The construction "between you and I" is an example of hypercorrection. Somewhere along the way, in the process of trying to teach people that when a list of people including yourself is the subject of the verb, you say something like "Bob, Alice, and I did X" (instead of "Bob, Alice, and me did X" or ("Me, Bob, and Alice did X"), people simplified that to always saying "and I" instead of "and me". I frequently hear things like "give it to him and I", and such. So, it certainly is in common usage. But, per my example above, it's not historically grammatical, by any means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree completely with JAM's answer.

However, there is one fundamental misunderstanding I see in your question: You are attempting to apply the standard rules of English grammar to a dialect which does not necessarily abide by all of them.

Supposedly this [song was transcribed](http://www.appalachianhistory.net/2011/12/i-tried-to-get-her-to-sing-all-song.html) by John Jacob Niles from a song sung by the daughter of an itinerant preacher in the extreme western part of North Carolina in 1933. Assuming the preacher in question mostly stuck to his dialect area, this would make the original author a speaker of [Appalachian English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English)

This is probably the *lowest* prestige English dialect found in the USA. About the only place you will find it in popular media is in [Bluegrass music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluegrass_music). Many English speakers have severe trouble understanding it in spoken form. So if you go looking through an AE song for "wrong" usages of English, you are likely to find yourself in a target-rich environment.

That being said, I can't find anything about unusual uses of "I" as a direct object in that dialect (in fact, I think AE is more likely to unexpectedly [substitute "me" for "I"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English#Pronouns_and_demonstratives), rather than the other way around). Most likely, as JAM said, this was just done to make that one line rhyme.

Comment: Your point of applying rules of "correct" English is  well taken.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it should be 'like me' - you are absolutely right. They just wrote it as the incorrect 'I' to rhyme with sky. This is probably a case of [poetic licence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poetic_licence#English).

Comment: While I do not go so far as some anti-prescriptivists on this site, your *Of course ...* and *incorrect* are a bit didactic in light of your recognition of the poesy.

Comment: Hi @bib! I do agree with you, but I could never have persuaded my primary school teacher that 'I' was acceptable in a similar sentence of my own composition.

Comment: Maybe if it was in iambic pentameter ... ?